# Javascript validate list of email addresses and names comma separated

Tags: javascript, arrays, string, split

I need to validate a textbox that will accept a list of names and email addresses that are separated by commas. For an example check the picture below.

> How I want to separate by name and emails:
>   [image]

The code example is if I only separate by email address and I want to extend such a feature.

```
for (var i = 0; i < $scope.emailAddresses.length; i++) {
    var addr = $scope.emailAddresses[i];
    if (addr.address !== null && addr.address !== "") {
        message.users.push({email: addr.address});
    }
}
if($scope.massAddUsers !== undefined)
{
    var massEmails = $scope.massAddUsers.split(",");
    for(var j = 0; j < massEmails.length; j++)
    {
        var massEmailAddr = massEmails[j];
        if (massEmailAddr !== null && massEmailAddr.trim() !== "") {
            message.users.push({email: massEmailAddr.trim()});
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should simply split the string first at every comma separated value, then loop through the array, up until there are only 3 elements left. Using splice, you can create a new array everytime and assign `firstName`, `lastName` and `email` to those array elements, because you know they belong together.

```
    // Get the string   
    var content = $scope.theUserInput;
    // Split string at every comma, which makes every comma seperated value an array element
    var array = content.split(',');
    // For every array element as long as there are at least 3 left
    while(array.length > 2) {
      // Take first 3 array element (e.g. felix, fritz, mail@a.com) and assign it to variables: first, last and email
      const [first, last, email] = array.splice(0,3);
      // Do your email verification here ...
      // then push to array all together:
      $scope.users.push({
        firstname: first,
        lastname: last,
        email: email
     });
```

A complete example: http://jsfiddle.net/U3pVM/42477/

Answer (score 1):

As answered in [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46155/how-to-validate-an-email-address-in-javascript) you can validate email adresses by using

```
function validateEmail(email) {
    var re = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
    return re.test(String(email).toLowerCase());
}
```

and use it like

```
var massEmails = $scope.massAddUsers.split(",");
for(massEmailAddr of massEmails ){
    massEmailAddr = massEmailAddr.trim();
    if(validateEmail(massEmailAddr)){
        message.users.push({email: massEmailAddr});
    }
    else if (massEmailAddr !== "") {
        message.users.push({name: massEmailAdd});
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
  const list = input.split(",");
  const result = [];

  while(list.length > 2) {
    const [first, last, email] = list.splice(0, 3);
    // validate
    result.push({ first, last, email });
 }
```

Comment: How can I adjust my current email algorithm to include the names

Comment: How do I use splice to have the first , last and email in the correct order

Comment: While this code snippet may be the solution, [including an explanation](//meta.stackexchange.com/questions/114762/explaining-entirely-‌​code-based-answers) really helps to improve the quality of your post. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, and those people might not know the reasons for your code suggestion.

Comment: @yivi i put the same effort into answering the OP put into asking.